# Change headers in admin posts list

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-admin

Is there anyway to show different information shown about custom post types in their list in the admin, wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=myposttype ?

Obviously I could rip it apart by adding php or js to the admin_head action, but is there a core wp way.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/3531/1468 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean change the columns that show op on the list of posts/custom post types
the there is a "WordPress way" to do that, take a look at http://shibashake.com/wordpress-theme/add-custom-post-type-columns
and [jan answer to a similar question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3531/how-can-i-add-columns-to-the-post-edit-listing-to-show-my-custom-post-data/3532#3532)

Hope this Helps