# Adding a second custom taxonomy to a custom post type (both shown in its table)?

Tags: custom-taxonomy

The following code provided by [Mike Schinkel](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/89/mikeschinkel), creates a custom post type and a custom taxonomy. It makes the taxonomy to show up in the custom post type's column. Finally, it inserts some default terms.

I would like to insert a second taxonomy for the custom post type (Page Content) called: **Locations**.

(this second custom taxonomy should also show up in the column of the custom post type)

How can I modify the code to archive that?

```
<?php

/**
 * Create the Page Content custom post type and the Page Section custom taxonomy
 */
add_action('init', 'my_init_method');

if (!class_exists('YourSite_PageContent')) {
 class YourSite_PageContent {
   static function on_load() {
     add_action('init',array(__CLASS__,'init'));
     add_filter('manage_page_content_posts_columns',
         array(__CLASS__,'manage_page_content_posts_columns'));
     add_filter('manage_posts_custom_column',
         array(__CLASS__,'manage_posts_custom_column'),10,2);
     add_action('restrict_manage_posts',
         array(__CLASS__,'restrict_manage_posts'));
     add_filter('parse_query',
         array(__CLASS__,'parse_query'));
   }
   static function init() {
     register_post_type('page_content',array(
       'labels' => array(
         'name' => __( 'Page Content' ),
         'singular_name' => __( 'Page Content' ),
         'add_new_item' => 'Add New Page Content',
         'edit_item' => 'Edit Page Content',
         'new_item' => 'New Page Content',
         'search_items' => 'Search Page Content',
         'not_found' => 'No Page Content found',
         'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Page Content found in trash',
       ),
       'public' => true,
       'hierarchical' => false,
       'taxonomies' => array( 'page_sections'),
       'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail','custom-fields'),
       'rewrite' => array('slug'=>'page_content','with_front'=>false),
     ));
     register_taxonomy('page_sections','page_content',array(
       'hierarchical' => true,
       'labels' => array(
         'name' => __( 'Page Sections' ),
         'singular_name' => __( 'Page Section' ),
         'add_new_item' => 'Add New Page Section',
         'edit_item' => 'Edit Page Section',
         'new_item' => 'New Page Section',
         'search_items' => 'Search Page Section',
         'not_found' => 'No Page Sections found',
         'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Page Sections found in trash',
         'all_items' => __( 'All Page Sections' ),
       ),
       'query_var' => true,
       'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'page_sections' ),
       ));
     if (!get_option('yoursite-page-content-initialized')) {
       $terms = array(
         'Footer',
         'Header',
         'Front Page Intro',
         'Front Page Content',
         );
       foreach($terms as $term) {
         if (!get_term_by('name',$term,'page_sections')) {
           wp_insert_term($term, 'page_sections');
         }
       }
       update_option('yoursite-page-content-initialized',true);
     }
   }
   function manage_page_content_posts_columns($columns){
     $new = array();
     foreach($columns as $key => $title) {
       if ($key=='author') // Put the Page Sections column before the Author column
         $new['page_sections_column'] = 'Page Sections';
       $new[$key] = $title;
     }
     return $new;
   }
   function manage_posts_custom_column( $column,$post_id ) {
     global $typenow;
     if ($typenow=='page_content') {
       $taxonomy = 'page_sections';
       switch ($column) {
       case 'page_sections_column':
         $page_sections_column = get_the_terms($post_id,$taxonomy);
         if (is_array($page_sections_column)) {
           foreach($page_sections_column as $key => $page_sections) {
             $edit_link = get_term_link($page_sections,$taxonomy);
             $page_sections_column[$key] = '<a href="'.$edit_link.'">' . $page_sections->name . '</a>';
           }
           echo implode(' | ',$page_sections_column);
         }
         break;
       }
     }
   }
   function parse_query($query) {
     global $pagenow;
     $qv = &$query->query_vars;
     if ($pagenow=='edit.php' &&
         isset($qv['taxonomy']) && $qv['taxonomy']=='page_sections' &&
         isset($qv['term']) && is_numeric($qv['term'])) {
       $term = get_term_by('id',$qv['term'],'page_sections');
       $qv['term'] = $term->slug;
     }
   }
   function restrict_manage_posts() {
     global $typenow;
     global $wp_query;
     if ($typenow=='page_content') {
       $taxonomy = 'page_sections';
       $page_sections = get_taxonomy($taxonomy);
       wp_dropdown_categories(array(
         'show_option_all' =>  __("Show All {$page_sections->label}"),
         'taxonomy'        =>  $taxonomy,
         'name'            =>  $taxonomy,
         'orderby'         =>  'name',
         'selected'        =>  $wp_query->query['term'],
         'hierarchical'    =>  true,
         'depth'           =>  3,
         'show_count'      =>  true,  // This will give a view
         'hide_empty'      =>  true,   // This will give false positives, i.e. one's not empty related to the other terms. TODO: Fix that
       ));
     }
   }
 }
 YourSite_PageContent::on_load();
}
```

[image]

**EDIT (What I've done so far with no PHP skills):**

By modyfing the code this is what I've done so far:

```
<?php

/**
 * Create the Page Content custom post type and the Page Section custom taxonomy
 */
add_action('init', 'my_init_method');

if (!class_exists('YourSite_PageContent')) {
 class YourSite_PageContent {
   static function on_load() {
     add_action('init',array(__CLASS__,'init'));
     add_filter('manage_page_content_posts_columns',
         array(__CLASS__,'manage_page_content_posts_columns'));
     add_filter('manage_posts_custom_column',
         array(__CLASS__,'manage_posts_custom_column'),10,2);
     add_action('restrict_manage_posts',
         array(__CLASS__,'restrict_manage_posts'));
     add_filter('parse_query',
         array(__CLASS__,'parse_query'));
   }
   static function init() {
     register_post_type('page_content',array(
       'labels' => array(
         'name' => __( 'Page Content' ),
         'singular_name' => __( 'Page Content' ),
         'add_new_item' => 'Add New Page Content',
         'edit_item' => 'Edit Page Content',
         'new_item' => 'New Page Content',
         'search_items' => 'Search Page Content',
         'not_found' => 'No Page Content found',
         'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Page Content found in trash',
       ),
       'public' => true,
       'hierarchical' => false,
       'taxonomies' => array( 'page_sections'),
       'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail','custom-fields'),
       'rewrite' => array('slug'=>'page_content','with_front'=>false),
     ));
     register_taxonomy('locations','page_content',array(
       'hierarchical' => true,
       'labels' => array(
         'name' => __( 'Locations' ),
         'singular_name' => __( 'Page Section' ),
         'add_new_item' => 'Add New Page Section',
         'edit_item' => 'Edit Page Section',
         'new_item' => 'New Page Section',
         'search_items' => 'Search Page Section',
         'not_found' => 'No Page Sections found',
         'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Page Sections found in trash',
         'all_items' => __( 'All Page Sections' ),
       ),
       'query_var' => true,
       'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'locations' ),
       ));
     register_taxonomy('page_sections','page_content',array(
       'hierarchical' => true,
       'labels' => array(
         'name' => __( 'Page Sections' ),
         'singular_name' => __( 'Page Section' ),
         'add_new_item' => 'Add New Page Section',
         'edit_item' => 'Edit Page Section',
         'new_item' => 'New Page Section',
         'search_items' => 'Search Page Section',
         'not_found' => 'No Page Sections found',
         'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Page Sections found in trash',
         'all_items' => __( 'All Page Sections' ),
       ),
       'query_var' => true,
       'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'page_sections' ),
       ));
     if (!get_option('yoursite-page-content-initialized')) {
       $terms = array(
         'Footer',
         'Header',
         'Front Page Intro',
         'Front Page Content',
         );
       foreach($terms as $term) {
         if (!get_term_by('name',$term,'page_sections')) {
           wp_insert_term($term, 'page_sections');
         }
       }
       update_option('yoursite-page-content-initialized',true);
     }
   }
   function manage_page_content_posts_columns($columns){
     $new = array();
     foreach($columns as $key => $title) {
       if ($key=='author') // Put the Page Sections column before the Author column
         $new['page_sections_column'] = 'Page Sections';
       $new[$key] = $title;
     }
     return $new;
   }
   function manage_posts_custom_column( $column,$post_id ) {
     global $typenow;
     if ($typenow=='page_content') {
       $locations_taxonomy = 'locations';
       $page_sections_taxonomy = 'page_sections';
       switch ($column) {
       case 'locations_column':
         $locations_column = get_the_terms($post_id,$locations_taxonomy);
         if (is_array($locations_column)) {
           foreach($locations_column as $key => $locations) {
             $edit_link = get_term_link($locations,$locations_taxonomy);
             $locations_column[$key] = '<a href="'.$edit_link.'">' . $locations->name . '</a>';
           }
           echo implode(' | ',$locations_column);
         }
         break;
       case 'page_sections_column':
         $page_sections_column = get_the_terms($post_id,$page_sections_taxonomy);
         if (is_array($page_sections_column)) {
           foreach($page_sections_column as $key => $page_sections) {
             $edit_link = get_term_link($page_sections,$page_sections_taxonomy);
             $page_sections_column[$key] = '<a href="'.$edit_link.'">' . $page_sections->name . '</a>';
           }
           echo implode(' | ',$page_sections_column);
         }
         break;
       }
     }
   }
   function parse_query($query) {
     global $pagenow;
     $qv = &$query->query_vars;
     if ($pagenow=='edit.php' &&
         isset($qv['taxonomy']) && $qv['taxonomy']=='page_sections' &&
         isset($qv['term']) && is_numeric($qv['term'])) {
       $term = get_term_by('id',$qv['term'],'page_sections');
       $qv['term'] = $term->slug;
     }
   }
   function restrict_manage_posts() {
     global $typenow;
     global $wp_query;
     if ($typenow=='page_content') {
       $taxonomy = 'page_sections';
       $page_sections = get_taxonomy($taxonomy);
       wp_dropdown_categories(array(
         'show_option_all' =>  __("Show All {$page_sections->label}"),
         'taxonomy'        =>  $taxonomy,
         'name'            =>  $taxonomy,
         'orderby'         =>  'name',
         'selected'        =>  $wp_query->query['term'],
         'hierarchical'    =>  true,
         'depth'           =>  3,
         'show_count'      =>  true,  // This will give a view
         'hide_empty'      =>  true,   // This will give false positives, i.e. one's not empty related to the other terms. TODO: Fix that
       ));
     }
   }
 }
 YourSite_PageContent::on_load();
}
```

[image]

**I'm still struggling with this line:**

```
   function manage_page_content_posts_columns($columns){
     $new = array();
     foreach($columns as $key => $title) {
       if ($key=='author') // Put the Page Sections column before the Author column
         $new['locations_column'] = 'Locations';
         $new['cb'] = '<input type="checkbox">';
         $new['title'] = 'Title';
         $new['page_sections_column'] = 'Page Sections';
       $new[$key] = $title;
     }
     return $new;
   }
```

**I can't manage to place Page Sections before Locations.**

How to solve this?

Comment: why are some WPSE members encouraging the use of classes like this? Thiswill just make it even harder for PHP beginners to understand OOP.

Comment: @One Trick Pony So this can be accomplished without using classes? (by the way, what's a WPSE member)?

Comment: WPSE = wordpress stackexchage

Comment: @WPSE I thought WPSE = WordPress Super Elite members.

Comment: @One Trick Pony: Your question was already [answered](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/using-oop-in-themes/5790#5790) quite eloquently.

Comment: Not really, no valid reasons were give there why classes should be used in a procedural manner. I think I should re-edit that question giving the code above as a example of class misuse

Comment: I personally find the OOP-approach easier to understand. Anyway, this question isn't here to start a flame war via comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the following in my filter hook `manage_edit-<post-type>_columns`

```
add_filter( 'manage_edit-visitor_columns', array( &$this, '_wp_filter_visitor_columns' ) );

public function _wp_filter_visitor_columns( $columns )
{
    $columns = array(
            'cb' => '<input type="checkbox" />',
            'title' => 'Name',
            'type' => 'Type',
            //'state' => 'Current State',
            'id' => 'Visitor ID',
            'acct' => 'Using Account',
        );

    return $columns;
}
```

And to filter the column view, I use the following:

```
add_action( 'manage_posts_custom_column', array( &$this, '_wp_filter_visitor_column_view' ) );

public function _wp_filter_visitor_column_view( $column )
{
    global $post;
    if ( $column == "type" )
    {
        //$terms = get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'v_types', '', ', ', '' );
        //echo strip_tags( $terms );

        $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'v_types' );
        echo $terms[0]->name;
    }
    elseif ( $column == "state" OR $column == "workstation" )
    {
        $workstation = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'v_workstation', true );
        if ( $column == "workstation" ) echo $workstation;
        elseif ( $column == "state" ) echo 'Not coded....';
    }
    elseif ( $column == "id" )
    {
        echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'v_id', true );
    }
    elseif ( $column == "acct" )
    {
        $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'v_accounts' );
        echo $terms[0]->name;
    }
}
```

I hope this helps you.